# THREE.js Code only runs when there is breakbpoint

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am trying the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var xpos = -80;
var ypos= 15;
var teethCount=0;
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

var object = event.content;

teeth.push(object);

});
loader.load( 'obj/tooth1.obj' );
loader.load('obj/tooth2.obj');

for(var i = 0; i<32; i++)
{

teeth[i].position.x=xpos;
teeth[i].position.y=ypos;
scene.add(teeth[i]);
}
```

the for loop only runs when I set a breakpoint on its statements. Any suggestion

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Please explain how you arrived at that conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you suppose to wait until load event fires before entering loop ?